# How to fix the overlapping navbar elements on small screen created using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, navbar

Navbar brand name and button overlapping

[image: Navbar brand name and button overlapping]

This is ther desired result on small screen

[image: This is ther desired result on small screen]

navbar code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default micah-navbar-bg">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-left" href="#"> <img src="/sites//cologo.png" alt="logo"></a><p style="display:inline-block;">Company name</p>
    <button id="quickLinksbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger ">QUICK LINKS</button>    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
        <p class="navbar-text">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Css for quick links

```
#quickLinksbtn{
position: absolute;
right: 100px;
margin-top: 45px;
border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: i think there is less space for  ham burger due to large size of logo. decrease the logo size.
or make a proper snippet for demonstration of you problem-

Comment: have you used any media queries? hard to tell, could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: There's only so much that will fit horizontally on a small screen, so you've got to make choices. I would hide the 'Company Name' text and the 'QUICK LINKS' button. The screen won't get any wider as you seem to wish in the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusion that I think might be happening. The"quick links" square is not going to be able to remain the same size, nor is the logo, nor is the nav-button.

This is why they are overlapping.

Personally: I would just build a mobile version of the site exactly how you want it to look on mobile and put it all in a div and have that div "display: none" on anything bigger than say 800px. And "display:block" on anything smaller than that.

Likewise your desktop nav section would be the opposite.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   .mobile-nav{display:block;}
   .desktopnav{display:none;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
   .mobile-nav{display:none;}
   .desktopnav{display:block;}
}
```